# Seleccionar fecha y poner un botón que indicará qué día de la semana (Lunes a Domingo) corresponde con la fecha introducida

Tags: javascript

Quiero mostrar con un botón el día de la semana ( Lunes a Domingo ), a que corresponde un fecha introducida, en javascript.
No me funciona y no encuentro el error. Estoy aprendiendo y voy un poco perdida. Os copio el código para ver si me podéis ayudar.

```js
function alertDiaDeSemana(){ 
    var d=new Date(document.getElementById("fecha")).value;
    var diadesemana=new Array(7);
    diadesemana[0]="Domingo";
    diadesemana[1]="Lunes";
    diadesemana[2]="Martes";
    diadesemana[3]="Miércoles";
    diadesemana[4]="Jueves";
    diadesemana[5]="Viernes";
    diadesemana[6]="Sábado";
    var n= diadesemana[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML=n;

    alert("La fecha seleccionada es:"+ n);               
}
```

```html
<p>Fecha de la Encuesta:</p>

<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha"  value="2019-01-01" > 

<button type="button" onclick="alertDiaDeSemana()" value="Mostrar Día Semana">Mostrar Dia Semana</button>
```

Gracias

Comment: El problema es que estas buscando el atributo value de la instancia `Date` y en cambio debería de ser del boton. `    var d = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
`

Answer (score 3):

Como te dije en el comentario, estabas buscando el atributo value en la instancia `Date` cuando debería de ser

```
var d = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
```

Respecto a tu código, no es necesario instanciar un array y luego asignarle los valores, puedes hacerlo directamente.

```js
var diadesemana = ["Domingo", "Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"]
console.log(diadesemana)
```

También  se ve mucho más limpio.

Answer (score 0):

tienes dos problemas, el primero es que al pedir la fecha de tu input estas haciendo mal, debes hacerlo así.

```
var d=new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
```

Luego de eso debes aumentar un dia

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
```

Espero que sea de mucha ayuda, Saludos.

El codigo completo sería:

```
<p>Fecha de la Encuesta:</p>

<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="2019-01-01">

<button type="button" onclick="alertDiaDeSemana()" value="Mostrar Día Semana">Mostrar Dia Semana</button>
<script>
    function alertDiaDeSemana(){ 
var d=new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

var diadesemana=new Array(7);
diadesemana[0]="Domingo";
diadesemana[1]="Lunes";
diadesemana[2]="Martes";
diadesemana[3]="Miércoles";
diadesemana[4]="Jueves";
diadesemana[5]="Viernes";
diadesemana[6]="Sábado";
var n= diadesemana[d.getDay()];
document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML=n;

alert("La fecha seleccionada es:"+ n);
```

}

Comment: No creo que sea valido, ya que en javascript el primer dia de la semana es domingo(0), por lo cual  con  `d.getDate() + 1`  obtendras el dia siguiente. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay)

Comment: ¿Intentaste probar el código? A mi no me da error.

Comment: Si, lo probe y no da error, pero da un resultado diferente que no es. Ejemplo: El dia 01 de Enero  de 2019(2019-01-01) es un Martes  y el resultado de tu codigo dice que es un Miércoles, por lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: A mi me da correctamente de esa forma, podría ser el formato de idioma de la pc.